# Manter dados de formulário ao abrir e fechar extensão?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensão

Estou criando uma extensão para Google Chrome, onde o usuário preencherá um formulário através desta.

**Como funciona:**

1. O usuário clica no ícone da extensão e aparece um popup com
   formulário;
2. Começa o preenchimento do formulário;
3. Termina preenchimento;
4. Envia formulário;
5. Fim.

**Problema:**

1. O usuário clica no ícone da extensão e aparece um popup com
   formulário;
2. Começa o preenchimento do formulário;
3. Usuário clica no ícone da extensão sem querer ou fora do popup;
4. Extensão fecha;
5. Usuário abre novamente;
6. Dados já preenchidos foram perdidos;
7. Extensão torna-se inviável;
8. Fim.

Eu queria saber como não perder estes dados, mas não sei nem como pesquisar este tipo de problema, no Google. Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Você já fez o formulário e aconteceu isso, ou está imaginando que vai acontecer? Sugiro [edit] e por o código da parte que está pronta para que a ajuda seja em cima de informações mais concretas.

Answer (score 1):

Entendi, você quer evitar de perder os dados em quanto não concluir o formulário acaso feche acidentalmente o popup da extensão, é isto?

Você pode usar `localStorage`, por exemplo:

```
localStorage.setItem('meuForm', '... dados do form ...');
```

E carregar os dados assim:

```
localStorage.getItem('meuForm');
```

Claro que isto não vai fazer nada automaticamente, você tem que fazer uma função que leia todos inputs e associe cada um a um tipo de chave no `localStorage`, você pode usar `JSON.stringify` para salvar e `JSON.parse` para recarregar, ou então pode usar vários `setItem`, por exemplo:

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" name="nome">
    <input type="text" name="sobrenome">
    <select name="sexo">
        <option name="">Selecione...</option>
        <option name="femi">Feminio</option>
        <option name="masc">Masculino</option>
    </select>
    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

O Javascript ficaria assim:

```js
(function() {
    var campos;

    //Detecta alterações nos inputs, textareas e selects
    function eventosRascunho() {
        campos = document.querySelectorAll("#meuForm input, #meuForm textarea, #meuForm select");

        for (var i = campos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (campos[i].tagName === "SELECT") {
                campos[i].addEventListener("change", salvaRascunho);
            } else {
                campos[i].addEventListener("input", salvaRascunho);
                campos[i].addEventListener("keyup", salvaRascunho);
                campos[i].addEventListener("paste", salvaRascunho);
                campos[i].addEventListener("cut",   salvaRascunho);
            }
        }
    }

    //Salva rascunho no localStorage
    function salvaRascunho() {
        for (var i = campos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var nameAttr = campos[i].getAttribute("name");

            if (nameAttr) {
                localStorage.setItem(nameAttr, campos[i].value);
            }
        }
    }

    //Limpa rascunho no localStorage
    function limparRascunho() {
        for (var i = campos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var nameAttr = campos[i].getAttribute("name");

            if (nameAttr) {
                localStorage.removeItem(nameAttr);
            }
        }
    }

    //Restaura rascunho para os <select>
    function restauraHtmlSelect(options, valor) {
        for (var i = options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (options[i].value === valor) {
                options[i].selected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Carrega rascunho se existir
    function carregarRascunho() {
        //Verifica se os rascunhos estão vazios
        if (localStorage.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        for (var i = campos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var dados = localStorage.getItem(campos[i].getAttribute("name"));

            if (!dados) {
                continue;
            }

            if (campos[i].tagName === "SELECT") {
                restauraHtmlSelect(campos[i].querySelectorAll("option"));
            } else {
                campos[i].value = dados;
            }
        }
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        eventosRascunho();
    };
})();
```

Após enviar o formulário com sucesso use a função `limparRascunho();` para apagar os dados e evitar que o form restaure eles.